# App not shown on Play Store website, or on devices without SIM card

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, manifest

I published an app on the Play Store, but I can't see it on the website and on devices without SIM cards. It is an application for smartphones and tablets. 
I changed my manifest like this :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"  android:required="false" />

<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:xlargeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

I also changed the description so I can use keywords to search it. It is working well on devices with a sim card only, but can't be found otherwise. 
I'm not using telephony hardware on my app, so I don't understand why it can't be only seen on devices without sim cards and the website.

Comment: Obvious step is to check how merged manifest looks like. It could be different because of used libraries...

Comment: I checked the merged manifest, it looks the same. But inside some other manifests the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is different. Is it a problem ?